# Subgroup as quotient of normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

$N \lhd G$ then we get the group $G/N$.

1. Can any subgroup of $G$ be written in the form $G/N$ ?
2. Can we always identify $G/N$ with a subgroup of $G$ and if so is it unique?
   (like for internal direct product we can do.)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried? I always used to tell my pupils to test their conjectures on the groups of order at most $8$. There are only fourteen of them, it won't take more than half-an-hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to 1. No: take $G$ a non-abelian simple group. Answer to 2. No: take $G$ the quaternion group of order $8$ and $N=Z(G)$.

Comment: Strictly for $1$ $G$ must be a non-cyclic simple group or we cannot choose a non-trivial subgroup.

Comment: Point taken, added *non-abelian*, thanks @Fishbane

Answer (score 2):

For positive results in the direction of your question, check :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem

Your question 2 basically is satisfied if $G \cong N (G/N)$. The Schur–Zassenhaus theorem (link above) says that if $G$ is a finite group and $N$ is a normal subgroup such that $\gcd(|N|,|G|/|N|)=1$ then $G$ is a semi-direct product of $N$ and $G/N$. Inparticular there is a subgroup isomorphic to $G/N$. For infinite groups there is already an answer which gives counter example.

check out:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Q8
for counter example to your question 2. Same example as given in another answer.